# Typeahead - Bootstrap 3 - Doesn't pass selected typeahead

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

As below you can see when I select a typeahead option and click submit, it does not save it and indeed doesn't pass it at all when I raise it.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

This may be linked to a problem I have occasionally of two typeaheads appearing, I am not sure. I am also allowing the params. It works when I remove the JS below.

```
  $('.first_goal_box').typeahead([
    {
      name: 'Scorers',
      prefetch: './dashboard.json'
    }

  ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched it over to [Typeahead for Bootstrap 3](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead).

```
$.get('./dashboard.json'. function(data){
  $(".typeahead").typeahead({ source:data});
},'json');
```